# Using jQuery, how can I make all cell in a html table row bold?

Tags: jquery, html

What is the best way to make a table row bold using jQuery?  Do I have to loop through each td ?  If there a better way to set a table row bold all at once? The tr has a class associated with it (to be able to reference).

Comment: how do you know which cells have to be made bold? can you share the target html

Comment: Use CSS. Why do you want to do it with jquery?

Comment: do you want to make all cells within the tr with a specific class bold

Comment: @PSL - because i need it to be dynamic

Comment: @leora you need to be more specific in your question in that case. Please put some more effort in your question.

Comment: @leora do you mean depending on some other condition

Comment: Best by what measure? Fastest? Easiest to maintain? Most succinct? Most flexible?

Comment: toggle a class that has the css rule in it

Comment: just use CSS on the class name, it's designed for styling. Use jquery to add/remove the class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will bold the font when you click on a table row

```
$('tr').click(function(e){ 
    $(this).css("font-weight","bold");
        e.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

here's a demo http://jsfiddle.net/Ctz3X/

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>one</td>
        <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>three</td>
        <td>four</td>
    </tr>
</table>

.boldme {
    font-weight: bold;
}

$("tr").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("boldme");
});
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tRpYx/).